# how to make JButton icon set to be stretch or zoom

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

friends.
In C# I can but backgroundImage of button is stretch or zoom, how can I do that for JButton in JAVA?

Answer (score 0):

Best way would be to use a ComponentListener/Adapter, implement componentResized() and resize the image.